# C# SerialPort io exception access denied

Tags: c#-4.0, serial-port

I have an app that is listening to a preconfigured com port (let's say it's COM6).
My VS project should send strings to that port so that the running app can get it's needed info.
But! While I'm trying to open a serial port via VS, I get an IO exception, saying:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Access to the port 'COM6' is denied.

From what I read on the web, the problem is that my app is currently using the port, but that's the whole point of my project.

EDIT:
That's the basic code I'm trying to run:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort ("COM6");
port.Open();

port.Write("1");
```

Getting my IO exception at line 2 
Many thanks for the replies.

Comment: Show your code, are you sure you don't connect twice?

Comment: I'm doing the most basic thing:

1)SerialPort port = new SerialPort ("COM6");
2)port.Open();
3)port.Write("1");
Getting my IO exception at line 2

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104809/c-sharp-access-denied-when-trying-to-access-communications-port/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104809/c-sharp-access-denied-when-trying-to-access-communications-port/)

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you have a COM6 port on the computer you are running this on. Does some other process have that port open? Only one process can open a serial port at a time.