# C# access denied when trying to access communications port?

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to make a simple Windows Form Application in Visual Studios that will allow me to control the brightness setting of an LED strip hooked up to an Arduino.

The programming inside the Arduino is already well and done, but the C# programming is what's giving me trouble.

When trying to send strings of information through the port, I receive the following message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.dll .
>   Additional information: Access to the port 'COM3' is denied.

Here is the piece of code that is giving me trouble:

```
  private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        String color = trackBar1.Value.ToString();

        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort myPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3");
        if (myPort.IsOpen == false){
         //if not open, open the port
            myPort.Open(); // Error is shown here.
        }
        if (myPort.IsOpen){
            myPort.WriteLine(color);
        }
    }
```

I haven't included any closing of the port because first I want to get this to work, and I'm not understanding what's going on. I'm pretty sure no other applications are using the port; the Arduino is plugged in to it via USB in order to receive it's power but other than that, it's not receiving or transmitting from any other process.

I've tried changing the port from COM3 to other ports, which is one of the main solutions given for similar questions, but still I get the same result.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Opening a serial port in a Scroll event is never correct, that event fires entirely too often.  SerialPort does not support rapidly opening and closing the port, there is a worker thread that needs to exit and that takes time.  Open a port you use in your constructor and keep it open for the life of your UI.

Comment: I agree when you say that it's not correct to place it in the Scroll event (I'm still learning the whole c# and visual studios approach) but the serial port doesn't necessarily have to Open each time it's fired, because it's encapsulated in the if statement. I'll keep the constructor part in mind though, if only I knew how to use constructors with UI's lol. Thanks @HansPassant !

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause of Access Denied errors on COM ports is the COM port already being opened by some other program. You can use [portmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896644.aspx) to see which program that is. It could well be your own program since you never properly close the port.

Comment: can it be because the serial monitor is using it or may be the Arduino IDE ?

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in one of the comments by N.K: Make sure the Serial Monitor is not working.